# webpack: Module not found

Tags: javascript, webpack

Здравствуйте. Только соприкоснулась с webpack и не совсем удачно :)
Установила webpack через npm:

```
 npm i -g webpack
```

Хотела сделать экспериментальную сборку из следующих js файлов.

**home.js**

```
'use strict';

let welcome = require('.welcome');

welcome("home");
```

**welcome.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (message) {
    alert('Welcome ${message}');
};
```

**Конфиг webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './home',
    output: {
        filename: 'build.js'
    }
};
```

Но на выходе получила следующие ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чем мб причина.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В том случае, если имя подключаемого модуля не содержит явный намек на путь, он ищется в node_modules и в аналогичных местах. Судя по всему, почему-то в пути модуля пропустился слэш, вместо

```
let welcome = require('.welcome');
```

должно быть

```
let welcome = require('./welcome');
```

и из-за этого интерпретатор считает его самым обычным модулем, а не ищет его относительно текущего модуля.

Comment: Все получилось. Буду знать. Спасибо большое :)